# JFrame is frozen by using a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I am trying to remove a component from a Frame once a JComboBox is selected. But when I select one  of the boxes the whole Frame freezes and you can't do anything other then resize or move it.

```java
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800 , 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane() , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Gui gui = new Gui();

        JComboBox<ParabolaType> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(ParabolaType.values());
        comboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("started");

            frame.remove(frame.getComponents().length - 1);
            frame.revalidate();

            System.out.println("finished");
        });

        frame.add(gui);
        frame.add(comboBox);
```

```
started
finished
```

It seems the EventQueue thread doesn't get stopped at all. Why is this  happening?

Comment: Maybe you are removing all of the components (by removing root container)?

Comment: @Antoniossss That's it! Although I don't understand why it freezes. The JComboBox is added to the Frame and not to a container. So deleting the last component in the Frame shouldn't it delete the ComboBox?

Comment: Try to create reproduceable example.

Comment: @Antoniossss I changed the code example to be more reproduceable. Why does it freeze completely even though the last component I delete in the JFrame should be The JComboBox. There isn't any root container to remove

Comment: _I am trying to remove a component from a Frame once a JComboBox is selected._ Why ? Tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: *"more reproduceable"* Something is either 'reproducible' or 'not reproducible'. The uncompilable code snippet above is 'not'. Next time please post a [mre]. And note to @Antoniossss: `[mre]` in a comment automatically expands to the words and link seen above. It's less typing for more information. ;)

Comment: The common way to approach changes to an already visible GUI is to add the different components or containers as cards of a `CardLayout`. But you'd need to follow the advice of @c0der before I could understand the GUI well enough to have any certainty a card layout would work for this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for `[mre]` i didnt know it is available and always been thinking how the hell all of SO users always include this nice mre link :) Now I know

Comment: @Antoniossss your delight prompted me to hunt down this page which includes [Editing help: comment formatting (& more **shorthand links**)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). There are some in there I could well use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because
`frame.remove(frame.getComponents().length - 1);`
removes the `JRootPane`, so you are removing the root container.

Having `frame.getContentPane().remove(comboBox);` instead will remove the combobox.

Here you have a working example

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(800, 800);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JLabel gui = new JLabel("okokok");
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"Someting1", "Something2"});
comboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("started");
    frame.getContentPane().remove(comboBox);
    frame.repaint();
    System.out.println("finished");
});
frame.add(gui);
frame.add(comboBox);
frame.setVisible(true);
```